# Solution for Outdoor Geolocation

Tags: sensors, gps

I am new to the Internet of Things space and would like to inquire if a solution exists / could be created for real-time geolocation of an intermittently mobile object (not an automobile)? The GeoLocation would have to work mostly outdoors and would need to transmit location every few minutes to some cloud-based system. The device will also need to have the ability to be switched on and off by a human being and/or programmatically when the object does not need to be tracked.

I am looking for a few questions to be answered:

1. Is there any product available which can achieve outdoor geolocation with <100 meter accuracy which costs less than $40 ?
2. If no such product exists, how complicated would it be for me (an IoT novice) to build a system that achieves outdoor geolocation using a raspberry pi (maybe for about $30 - $50)?

Any guidance or additional resources that would help me gain clarity is greatly appreciated.

**Here are the answers to some questions in the comments:**

1. How long does the device need to report location?
   A. I am assuming the device will be reporting location once every 5 minutes. The device will need to report location through out the day, maybe from 7 AM - 11 PM every day, so for about 16 hours a day (although this isn't a hard constraint i.e it could report for less time).
2. How large is the object?
   A. The object can be thought of as not being too large. It will be about 1.5 - 2 meters in height and about half a meter wide.
3. Does the mechanism need to be covert?
   A. No there is no special requirement for being covert w.r.t the geolocation process. However, the data once collected needs to be secure and the actual geolocation device should allow me to add layers of security into it to prevent malicious entities from manipulating the geolocation process and / or unauthorized entities collecting the geolocation data. However, an important feature that the device will need to have is the ability to be able to be switched on and off by a human.
4. What power source is available?
   A. For now, I am assuming that a power source will be intermittently available (i.e 1 - 2 hours a day), i.e the device will be charged once a day using a regular charging port. Or, if it would be possible for such a device to have rechargeable batteries, then some solution could be possible achieved with a set of 2 - 3 rechargeable batteries cycled through out the day, however I fear this will go over the $40 budget that I have set for such a device.
5. It needs to report location so often because the location of the object will govern certain processes in the backend. Think of it akin to a ride matching part of a ride-sharing service like Uber (only w.r.t the reason for frequent location reporting) wherein the location of a driver is collected at some frequency to match them with a trip.

What research was done previously:

1. One approach that I have thought about is to use cheap smart phones with GPS capabilities and deploy them instead of sensors on the objects. However, the cheapest smartphones that I was able to find were about $70, not to mention the phone plan requirements etc, as the geolocation will have to happen in the abscence of wifi.
2. Another device that I have looked at (although I must admit I didn't understand the explanation enough to evaluate if this would work for my application) is Apple's iBeacon devices. However, I do not have the answers to most of the aforementioned questions in the context of iBeacon devices.

Comment: No where enough information in the question. 1) How long does the device need to report location 2) how large is the object 3) does the mechanism need to be covert 4) What power source is available 5) Why does it need to report location so often

Comment: Also update the question with what research you did before asking the question.

Comment: @hardillb thanks for your detailed questions. I have added answers to most of your questions to the best of my ability. I must admit that I do not know enough about the IoT area and about sensors and their capabilities in general to understand too much from any research I've done so far. Hence I was looking for someone to point me toward potential solutions / devices that I could look further into, given my application hardware requirements.

Comment: How long was meant to be does it have to track for a day/week/month without being recharged. Does it need to be covert was meant to be does it have to be hidden for who ever may be moving the device

Comment: Yes the device may be re-charged every 8 - 10 hours. No it does not need to be covert. @hardillb.

Comment: Is the device guaranteed to always be in WiFI or BT distance? Don#'t forget LoRa. I.e. will it need a SIM Card or not? Do you want to track it in remote locations, such that you might need a satellite connection?  Do you need the location in close to real-time, or can it store details of its travels during the day and upload them when it comes back into range again?  Do you have any requirements for ruggedness (e.g IP 67)?

Comment: Are you happy to use an off the shelf tracker, or do you want to develop your own, for the fun/learning?

Comment: @Mawg , thanks for your response. No it is not guaranteed to be in WiFi distance as it will mostly be outdoors at places without WiFi most likely. If Bluetooth is available, it will have to be available on the device itself. The location needs to be close to real-time because it will be based on the location of this object (which may change frequently or from time to time ) that certain backend processes will proceed. So yes the location needs to be updated every 5 minutes. I am happy to use off the shelf tools provided they allow me to consume some sort of an API to receive the location.

Comment: Are you aware of [LoRa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LoRa) ?  Are repeaters an option, for your WiFi or BT ?  Is it only one object? If several, maybe a mesh network of the objects themselves, rather than repeaters?

Comment: @Mawg In the beginning there will be a few objects (I'm assuming 10 at the most all widely dispersed away from each other) but the system will require to be expanded much wider in the future to a few hundred or even thousands of such objects (all dispersed away from each other of course).  I will look further into the LoRa technology. 

My understanding of `repeaters` is that they are a cost-effective solution to strengthen wifi signals in areas where they were previously weak? Could repeaters be used to extend a wifi signal by 300 feet beyond its current limit? If so, it is worth exploring.

Comment: 300 feet? LoRa will handle that. As will repeaters. If you have multiple objects in that 300 foot radius, they can act as repeaters for each other - read about [mesh networks](https://internetofthingsagenda.techtarget.com/definition/mesh-network-topology-mesh-network). Btw, it's a good idea to update your question with some of this info, as not everyone will read all of the comments.

Comment: How much accuracy do you need on each location? GPS, to within 1 metre? Or positioning by WiFI, based on signal strength to determine proximity to a router. Such as https://www.infsoft.com/technology/sensors/wifi  etc

Comment: You could also attach RFID tags to your "objects" (honestly, no one is looking to steal your idea; the more info you give, the better that we can help ;-) and detect them moving past readers. Is the area of movement totally open, like a sports field, or is there any infrastructure in it, such as pillars/posts/anything else?

Comment: @Mawg thanks for all your comments. I will look into the RFID idea. The accuracy needs to be within about 15 - 20 meters of the object. There will not be multiple objects in a 300 foot radius. We may assume that the objects will be far removed from each other. I will update the question with the information in the comments. Thanks for your multiple suggestions and clarifications to my questions.

Comment: No problem, we are glad to help here. Plus, I love designing new projects ;-) Updating the question is a good idea. As always, GIGO - meaning that the more detailed info you can provide, the better help we can give. In this, we are refining the requirements. For RFID, read [Active RFID vs. Passive RFID: What’s the Difference?](https://blog.atlasrfidstore.com/active-rfid-vs-passive-rfid) - Hint: you need active & that page gives you an idea of battery life (years) (NFC would be no good) also read [What Is an RFID Reader's Maximum Range?](https://www.rfidjournal.com/blogs/experts/entry?10918)

Answer (score 2):

**Regarding question 1:**

There is a vast amount of GPS trackers (accuracy of a few meters) that are commercially available and that come with their own tracking server accessible via app or web-interface.
Normally, they either come with a built-in SIM-card or you have to put in a SIM-card yourself. The location is communicated either via SMS or via mobile data to the tracking server. Needless to say that you will have monthly running costs due to the SIM card.

Typically, they are used for tracking pets (e.g. cats) or vehicles, amongst others.
Their price range is quite wide, depending on where you order and what features they incorporate (e.g. microphone and/or speakers, additional WiFi). Nevertheless, you should be able to find one that is in your price range, if you search for **"GPS tracker"** on the standard platforms for electronic equipment.

**Regarding question 2:**

If you are worried about privacy, you can host your own tracking server on a Raspberry Pi. A popular solution is the [traccar server](https://www.traccar.org/server/), which is open source and free of charge.
You can use with compatible devices (listed on their homepage) or a Traccar client app on your mobile phone. 
For running the server you simply need a Raspberry Pi connected to the internet (no additional hardware required), with an exposed port for the traccar server.

Comment: Thanks @oh.dae.su , I was wondering if this (taccar server) solution would be if I didn't want to use the Taccar client app and wanted to write my own app to pull data in from the raspberry pi, would the taccar server allow me to achieve this ?

Comment: @Nikhil, I am pretty confident, you will be able to communicate with a traccar server using your own custom app. You simply need to implement one of the supported protocols. However, I never went into that direction and cannot give you further hints, how to go on.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will look into your suggestion further.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend the [TTGO T-Beam](https://blog.hackster.io/the-ttgo-t-beam-an-esp32-lora-board-d44b08f18628), or a similar device, using LoRaWAN.
[image]

Comment: This is basically a link only answer, we expect you to explain why this would be a good solution.